# how to Change the Fieldset leged in the click of radio button

Tags: jquery

how to change the  leged of field set
 When i click on Edi leavetype the legend should be changed to Edit Leave Type

My code is as follows

```
    <fieldset class="fieldset">
    <legend style="text-align: left; font-weight: bold; width: 100px; padding: 0px 0px 0px 6px;" class="legend">Add Leave Type</legend>
// At the above line Filedset leged is Add Leave Type 

    <table width="100%" border="2">
                  <tr>
                   <td align="center"> 
                       <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblLeaveType" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" 
                           RepeatDirection="Horizontal" 
                           onselectedindexchanged="rblLeaveType_SelectedIndexChanged"> 

                        <asp:ListItem Text="Add Leave Type" Value="1" Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Text="Edit Leave Type" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
// when Edit Leave type is true the legend should change to Edit Leave type
                       </asp:RadioButtonList>
                   </td>
                   </tr>
                 </table><br />

    </fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this , Give legend an id :-

```
$(document).ready(
  $("#RadioButtonID").click(function(){
    function() {
        $('#legendID').text('Edit Leave Type');
    }
  });
);
```

Answer (score 0):

For your particular code, you can use this:

```
$('#rblLeaveType').find('input[type="radio"]').click(function () {
    if ($(this).val() == 2 && $(this).not(':checked')) {
        $(this).parents('fieldset').find('legend').text('Edit Leave Type');
    } else {
        $(this).parents('fieldset').find('legend').text('Add Leave Type');
    }
});
```

### [Example in JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/drDKd/)